# Template member function error: clang doesn't match any member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang

I've write the following template member function but i can't call it without getting error by compiler:

```
template <class T, class A>
auto tpool::enqueue(T&& func, std::vector<A>&& args)
-> std::vector<std::future<decltype(std::forward<T>(func)(decltype(std::forward<A(args))::value_type))>>
{
    //...
}

tpool tp();
auto f = [] (int) { /* ... */ };
std::vector<int> args; 

tp.enqueue(f, args);
```

I get the following error by clang:

```
test_cpp.cpp:144:5: error: no matching member function for call to 'enqueue'
    tp.enqueue(f, args);

test_cpp.cpp:107:13: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = <lambda at test_cpp.cpp:140:11> &, A = int]: no matching function for call to 'forward'
auto tpool::enqueue(T&& func, std::vector<A>&& args)
```

Comment: By `tpool tp();` do you mean `tpool tp;`?

Comment: You have couple of syntax errors in there. `std::forward<A(args)` for e.g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class T, class A>
auto tpool::enqueue(T&& func, std::vector<A>&& args)
```

This makes `args` to be an rvalue reference, which accepts rvalue only, but in

```
std::vector<int> args; 
tp.enqueue(f, args);
```

`args` is an lvalue, thus the candidate is ignored.

Note that `T&& func` allows lvalues to be bound, because the template substitution can allow `T` itself be an lvalue reference, which we then have `(T&)&& == T&`. But this is not possible with `args`, as no matter what `A` is, `std::vector<...>&&` is always an rvalue reference of a vector.

---

If you are not going to copy or modify the `args` anyway, you could pass a const reference instead:

```
template <class T, class A>
auto tpool::enqueue(T&& func, const std::vector<A>& args)
```

You could also allow perfect-forwarding, by not specifying that the `args` must be a vector:

```
template <class T, class V>
auto tpool::enqueue(T&& func, V&& args)
    -> std::vector<std::future<decltype(func(args.front()))>>
```